# Plot counter of data points in matlpotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a `matplotlib` scatter plot like following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot,axis,show,pcolor,colorbar,bone

axiss = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
x,y = zip(*axiss)


labels = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4',
         'u5', 'u6', 'u7', 'u8',
         'u9', 'u10']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))
show()
```

Instead of labels I want to show how many data points are scattered on one point. For example in the data point I have marked in red, It should show '2'. And in the mouse hover event I need to see the labels. So in the example it should be 'u7' and 'u10'. Is it possible with `matplotlib`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got a little long, but I would first collect the unique element in `axiss` using `set` and count the number of each unique element. Then include that data into `scatter`'s third argument, the size of the points. I would also annotate each points according the the number of datasets in that point.

Now the interactive annotation is a tricky part. I could not find mouse-hover event catcher, but you can do pretty much the same thing for mouse-clicking event. Save the first script on this page http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Interactive_Plotting as `interactive_annotations.py` and import it in the script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot,axis,show,pcolor,colorbar,bone
import numpy as np

axiss = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]

# get unique elements
axiss_unique = list(set(axiss))
# get number of data at each datapoint
axiss_count = [axiss.count(x) for x in axiss_unique]

sc = 100 # scale up the datapoints for scatter
labels = [] # label each point according to number of data there
annotates = [] # intereactively label each point according to the datapoint name
for i in range(len(axiss_count)):
    labels.append('%i'%axiss_count[i])
    annotates.append( ' '.join(['u'+str(k) for k, j in enumerate(axiss) if j == axiss_unique[i]]))
    axiss_count[i] *= sc

x,y = zip(*axiss_unique)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# get offsets of the labels to each point
x_os, y_os = max(x)/20., max(y)/20.
ax.scatter(x, y, axiss_count)
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i]+x_os,y[i]+y_os), fontsize=15)

# interactive annotation
import interactive_annotations

af =  interactive_annotations.AnnoteFinder(x,y, annotates)
connect('button_press_event', af)

show()
```

Result is something like this.
[image]

You can edit `interactive_annotations.py` to change the offset of the annotations, fonts, etc.